# Livereload для Sublime Text 3 не отслеживает файлы с одинаковыми именами в разных каталогах

Tags: css, вёрстка, sublime-text, плагин, reload

Как заставить плагин Livereload для Sublime Text 3 отслеживать изменения в файлах с одинаковыми именами в разных каталогах, например: /style.css и /css/style.css? Если переименовать один из файлов, все работает.